# How to check if a page component is created by a navController or a modalController

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic3, angular5

I have a lazy loaded IonicPage Component.

Which can be called in two ways:

1. `navController.push('pageName');`
2. `modalController.create('pageName');`

Both work well.

Is there a way I can check from within the IonicPage Component to see if it has been created by the navController or the modalController?

Plan B. I can pass a navParam with both e.g. `isModal=true` to fix this, but I am curious if there is an easier way to check how a page is created.

Context: The page is a component with a list of say users. If the component is loaded as a page (see 1. above) then when we click on an user you can edit its details. But when the component is presented as a modal and we click on it, the details of the clicked user is passed back to the previous page for processing.